# Create a text file using the pandas dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to the python . I have the following dataframe

```
Document_ID OFFSET  PredictedFeature   word
    0         0             2000        abcd
    0         8             2000         is
    0         16            2200         a
    0         23            2200        good
    0          25           315        XXYYZZ
    1          0            2100       but
    1          5            2100       it 
    1          7            2100       can
    1          10           315        XXYYZZ
```

Now, In this dataframe what I trying to do is make a file which can be in a readable formt like ,

**abcd is 2000, a good 2200
but it can 2100,**

```
PredictedData    feature      offset  endoffset
  abcd is           2000       0         8
  a good           2200        16      23
   NewLine         315         25     25
 but it can        2100         0      7
```

this type of data. where if you see I trying same sequence of predictedFeatures are coming then I am concatening same words with it's value. If there is feature `315` then I am giving a new line to it.
SO, Is there any way though which I can do this ? Any help will be appreciated.
Thnaks

Comment: Provide a second table with the outcome you want

Comment: I have just updated the second table

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can do `groupby()`:

```
(df.groupby(['Document_ID', 'PredictedFeature'],as_index=False)
   .agg({'word':(' '.join),
         'OFFSET':('min','max')
        })
)
```

Output:

```
  Document_ID PredictedFeature        word    OFFSET    
                                      join    min max
0           0              315      XXYYZZ     25  25
1           0             2000     abcd is      0   8
2           0             2200      a good     16  23
3           1              315      XXYYZZ     10  10
4           1             2100  but it can      0   7
```